# Is this JQuery valid?

Tags: jquery

Is this JQuery valid? $("[name=enableTooltip]:checked")

What does it does?

Comment: you little lazy boy ... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more understandable:

```
$("input[name=enableTooltip]:checked")
```

This selects all inputs which has name attribute equals "enableTooltip" and checked status is true.

Example match:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="enableTooltip" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The selector `[attr=val]` is a shortcut for `*[attr=val]`. So `[name=enableTooltip]:checked` will select any element that’s name attribute value is “enableTooltip” and is checked ([`:checked`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checkbox) this implies that the element is an `INPUT` element of the type *checkbox*).